# Regex to list, to console print append is misbehaving due to match any character

Tags: c#, regex, string, console, append

Looking at the code below:

```
this.line = Regex.Matches(source, @".+(?<=\s(F|D|B|S|T))\d+.+").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();

            foreach (string item in this.line)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item + " text");
            }
```

You would expect this `source`:

```
HEADER
[    
Y22 Z48*2 T4 B12 Desc
X46 Y60*5 S2 D B13 P9
X104 Y124*2 F2 T1 B10 M21
]
...
```

to be appended as follows:

```
Y22 Z48*2 T4 B12 Desc text
X46 Y60*5 S2 D B13 P9 text
X104 Y124*2 F2 T1 B10 M21 text
```

But I am getting this:

```
 text48*2 T4 B12 Desc
 text60*5 S2 D B13 P9
 textY124*2 F2 T1 B10 M21
```

The appended string is overwriting the `item`. The reason this is happening from what I can tell is because of the `.+` where any character is matched infinite times until new line. But thats the point here. I am at a loss as to why this is happening. Ideas?

EDIT:

I open a text file and extract content between [ and ]. Add them to a list. Then for each group I try and do the above mentioned matching.
Now I have tested this by manually entering the string as suggested and it works fine, but for an opened text not so much? Can It be that the opened text is messing up the new line?

```
 fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filename);

 source = Regex.Matches(fileContents, @".(?<=\[)[^\[\]]+(?=\]).").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();

 this.line = Regex.Matches(source, @".+(?<=\s(F|D|B|S|T))\d+.+").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();

                foreach (string item in this.line)
```

EDIT2:
See answer.

Comment: Look, [it is working as expected](http://ideone.com/20r0rX).

Comment: well it's not working in VS 2013. And reason why I am creating a list is because this is just an example. In actuallity I am loading the modified lines to another list.

Comment: No, the issue lies somewhere else. Post all your actual relevant code.

Comment: Your first regex is actually equal to [`\[[^\[\]]+]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5b%5e%5c%5b%5c%5d%5d%2b%5d&i=HEADER%0d%0a%5b++++%0d%0aY22+Z48*2+T4+B12+Desc%0d%0aX46+Y60*5+S2+D+B13+P9%0d%0aX104+Y124*2+F2+T1+B10+M21%0d%0a%5d). The `File.ReadAllText` *opens a text file, reads all lines of the file, and then closes the file*, so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: This is all of the relevant code that I have to be honest.

Comment: Is it a recursive method? Do you get the same with `String.Concat`? `String.Join(" ", new[] {this.line, "item"})`?

Comment: can you try if `.+` matches a newline `\n` in VS2013? If this is the case, `RegexOptions.SingleLine` might be activated.

Comment: @stribizhev both options didnt work. Same result.

Comment: @bro Singleline is not activated by default AFAIK. Tried it and yup, makes no difference.

Comment: All I can say is that I only saw weird things when using a recursive method: lines were executed in reverse order. Here, regex has nothing to do with the described behavior.

Comment: @stribizhev thing is, when I remote the last ".+" from teh regex expresion it appends the line just fine.

Comment: Do you mean you have an RTL mark there, at the end of the line? Try to check for it with `Regex.IsMatch(this.line, @"[\u200F]")`. If yes, try using `@".+(?<=\s(F|D|B|S|T))\d+[^\n\u200F]+"` regex.

Comment: And another suggestion: `@".+(?<=\s(F|D|B|S|T))\d+[\P{Cf}-[\n]]+"`. Could you make sure there are no invisible characters in the matched text?

Comment: @stribizhev false on both accounts. Might have to change the expresion to not use `+` at the end of line i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way to go around this I think, but just ended up going though the source line by line and looking up if its a match and if yes, append to the line.

> ```
>            foreach (string line in source.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
>             {
>                 Regex regex = new Regex(@".+(?<=\s(F|D|B|S|T))\d+.+");
>                 Match match = regex.Match(line);
>                 if (match.Success)
>                     Console.WriteLine(line + " text");
>
>             }
> ```